# Python logging vs. write to file

Tags: python, logging, file-writing, bigdata

Which is more efficient? Is there a downside to using `open() -> write() -> close()` compared to using `logger.info()`?

PS. We are accumulating query logs for a university, so there's a perchance that it becomes big data soon (considering that the min-max cap of query logs per day is 3GB-9GB and it will run 24/7 constantly for a lifetime). It would be appreciated if you could explain and differentiate **in great detail** the efficiency in time and being error prone aspects.

Comment: I highly doubt that one application writing to a log file is considered "big data" unless you are generating megabytes of text per second.

Comment: If you think this is big data, you are in for a shock if you ever get to work with actual big data.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm sorry if ever I am quite overstating, it's just that we are accumulating an approximate 9GB maximum of query logs per day, and this engine of ours will be utilized by our university constantly since the day of integration.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes I do understand. But with 9GB of data per day, running 24/7 for a year, I guess we would reach that term soon enough within years. (Although we might be deleting the unnecessary ones for limited resources issues)

Comment: @AngeloSembrano: 9GB per day is not "big data" (not that there's a specific definition, but you know what I mean). All of your data can fit on a single hard drive uncompressed for the next 2 years.

Comment: @AngeloSembrano In a previous job we logged an average of 80,000 queries per second. I think you'll be alright.

Comment: @Blender There are single 6.5 TB drives?

Comment: @cricket_007: You can get an 8TB hard drive for like $250.

Comment: @Blender Oops, I keep forgetting how large single HDD's are getting :)

Comment: Big Data usually refers to complexity of the data, it very rarely means the size of the data - although generally those two have a strong correlation. Big Data simply means - a data set so large **or complex** that traditional tools cannot parse and extract any meaningful information from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the method that more closely describes what you're trying to do. Are you making log entries? Use `logger.*`. If (and only if!) that becomes a performance issue, then change it. Until then it's an optimization that you don't know if you'll ever need.

**Pros for `logging`**:

- It's semantic. When you see `logging.info(...)`, you know you're writing a log message.
- It's idiomatic. This is how you write Python logs.
- It's efficient. Maybe not *extremely* efficient, but it's so thoroughly used that it has lots of nice optimizations (like not running string interpolation on log messages that won't be emitted because of loglevels, etc.).

**Cons for `logging`:**

- It's not as much fun as inventing your own solution (which will invariably turn into an unfeatureful, poorly tested, less efficient version of `logging`).

Until you *know* that it's not efficient enough, I highly recommend you use it. Again, you can always replace it later if data proves that it's not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use a built-in facility unless you are facing issues with the built-in functionality.

So, use the built-in logging function. It is proven, tested and *very flexible* - something you cannot achieve with `open() -> f.write() -> close()`.